# Symfony 5 - Override Form Type Options

Tags: php, symfony, autocomplete, symfony5, tom-select

### The problem:

Hello, i am having a trouble with passing some options to the form fields in Symfony 5 Form Builder.

In the controller the form is being created:

```php
$form = $this->createForm(FooFormType::class, $foo);
```

In the `FooFormType.php` my **buildForm()** method looks like this:

```php
$builder
    ->add('collection', FooAutocompleteField::class, [ 
        'searchable_fields' => ['name'],
    ])
;
```

in the `FooAutocompleteField.php` i have only **getParent()** that returns the Symfony UX `ParentEntityAutocompleteType::class` and a **configureOptions()** which looks like this:

```php
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
       'class' => Foo::class,
       'searchable_fields' => ['override_me'],
    ]);
}
```

I need the `searchable_fields` to be replace within the `FooFormType.php`, ideally by passing an option in controller like this:

```php
$form = $this->createForm(FooFormType::class, $foo,[
    'searchable_fields' => ['name'],
]);
```

### What i've Tried:

1. Passing an option into builder like in example above
2. Adding `$resolver->setDefined('searchable_fields');` after ConfigureOptions of  `FooAutocompleteField.php`
3. I made a **buildForm()** method inside `FooAutocompleteField.php` and the **$options** does indeed change, but the defaults in *configureOptions()* are not overriden.

### Update 22.02.2023:

It seems that when i do this (add an attr option):

```php
$builder
    ->add('collection', FooAutocompleteField::class, [ 
        'searchable_fields' => ['name'],
        'attr' = [
           'class' => 'bg-primary',
           'placeholder' => 'THIS IS OVERRIDING',
        ]
    ])
;
```

The options are in fact overriding and getting passed to `FooAutocompleteField`!

But **why not the 'searchable_fields'**?

It seems like the initial form select options are overwritten, but the Ajax calls themselve use the Default configuration. Im stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue of symfony/ux: (Currently not really fixable.)

Here is the issue on github:
https://github.com/symfony/ux/issues/420

> You really cannot pass/override ANY options when you use an Ajax
> auto-complete field. This is because, on the Ajax call, we would have
> no way to re-create your AnyForm form (nor are we even aware of it).
> We simply re-create the FoodAutocompleteField and then use its
> query_builder.

Source : [Ryan Weaver on issue](https://github.com/symfony/ux/issues/474#issuecomment-1254999273)

Comment: So it looks like you will need to create a separate implementation for each use-case of differing options.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i did. `FooByIdAutocompleteField` and a `FooByNameAutocompleteField`. Will close this question ASAP :)

Comment: You do not need/want to close the question unless it is a duplicate instead choose this as the answer and it will be here to help future users.

Comment: Alright, but stack wont allow me to mark as answered until 2 days, thanks for the advice!